# Cakephp 2x can't retrieve hasMany relation data

Tags: php, cakephp

**my question is when i call the $data, i can't retrieve Comment, it return like this,why the comment doesn't return?**

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Event] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [url_id] => 22cbb58298af0fe62284324ccc020023
                [name] => 高尾山ハイキング
                [date] => 2017-05-06 00:00:00
                [memo] => 行こうぜ
                [is_available] => 1
                [created] => 2017-05-03 21:15:30
                [modified] => 2017-05-03 21:15:30
            )

        [Comment] => Array
            (
            )

    ))
```

> this is Event controller and event hasMany Comment, by the way i am
>   already finish some setup up at Model

```
$data = $this->Event->find('all',[
            'conditions' => [
                'Event.url_id' => $eventURL
            ],
            'contain' =>[
                'Comment'=>[
                    'conditions' => ['Comment.event_id' =>$eventURL],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong `'conditions' => ['Comment.event_id' =>$eventURL],` Does the Comment table has  `22cbb58298af0fe62284324ccc020023` in `event_id` column?

Comment: Share your both table structure as well. So we can get to know the association between them. As from the code the problem is with the association.

Comment: of cause Comment table has foreign key as event_id , heres the table
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
 `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
 `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `Index 2` (`event_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=20
;

Comment: Is Comments.event_id is associated with Event.id ? Put it in question

Comment: thanks @AmanRawat i got it. i thinks it is not associated with Event.id, thats why

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to manually add the foreign_key inside your `contain` key.

If your models are set up properly and you have `hasMany` records for `Event` in your `Comment` table, this should give you, what you expect.

```
$data = $this->Event->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'Event.url_id' => $eventURL
    ],
    'contain' =>[
        'Comment'
    ]
]);
```

If there is a `Comment` inside your database with an `event_id` of `1` you should get it.

If you don’t, please set `Configure::write('debug', 2)` and check your SQL debug output, what query is generated.